# reading input from a text file and using it in a function in C

Tags: c, text-files

How would I use input from a text file so that I could use it in a function, without saving the characters into an array? As I read from the text file a 1 will come up and I will go to "setParameters", where I would enter the rest of the parameters. Also in that function, I will use malloc.(if it does not make sense let me know so that I can clarify it, also I am new to C)

```
int val;
int choice;
 FILE *fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("afile.txt","r");
printf("\nError Detection/Correction");
printf("------------------------------\n");

choice = fscanf(fpointer,"%d",&val);
while(choice != 3)
{
    printf("1. Enter Parameters\n2. Enter Hamming Code\n3. Quit\n");
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: setParameters();
            break;

        case 2: checkError();
            break;

        case 3: printf("*** Program Terminated Normally");
            break;

        default: 
            printf("Not a valid entry");
        break;

    }//end of switch statment
```

Comment: Can you perhaps post any code that you already have?  Is this an assignment question?

Comment: what's `run`? I think you want `switch(val)` instead of `switch(choice)`

Comment: `choice = fscanf(fpointer,"%d",&val);
while(choice != 3)` --> `choice` will only be `0,1,EOF`

Comment: So should I change the while condition to "while(!feof(fpointer))"

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: `fscanf(fpointer,"%d",&val);` attempts to read text and convert that into an `int` for `val`.  Where does code then use `val`?

Comment: val is used in a function that is not posted on here

Comment: not sure what you want to ask @Blitzman. 
Do  you want to use val, in other functions without storing it to an array?
Do i get it right?

Comment: yes that is exactly right

Comment: @Blitzman, Did my answer help you.?

Answer (score 0):

**To take input from file in C (using fscanf):**

You need to initialize FILE pointer using `fopen` and then scan each input using `fopen`.

```
FILE *fpointer;
fpointer = fopen("afile.txt","r");
int ret;
while(ret = fscanf(fpointer," %d ",&val))
{
     if(ret == EOF)
     {
          break;
     }
     else
     {
         // use val variable here in code which is taken as input from file
     }
}
```

here, it is important to understand what ret variable is:

- EOF, if the pointer is reached end of file.
- 0, if no input matched with the variable
- >0, number of matched variables with the file input

**To take input from file in C++ (using fstrean):**

it is very easy to get input from a file. we just need to change `cin` to get input from file stream instead of standard input.

```
#include <fstream.h>

void main() {
    ifstream cin("afile.txt");
    int val;
    cin  >> val;

    // use val as variable in code.
}
```

this approach is very easy but only works in C++. it requires no file operations like fscanf . just changing cin will do the work :)

Comment: Observations: `while(ret = fscanf(fpointer," %d ",&val)
{
     if(ret == EOF || ret == 0)` won't compile; there's a `)` missing at minimum; and the `ret == 0` condition would never be true because the (fixed) while loop would prevent it being reached.  I'd use `while ((ret = fscanf(fpointer, "%d", &val)) == 1)` which only enters the loop if the input is successful.  Note that [trailing blanks in `scanf()` format strings are a UI disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/) too, and the leading blank is superfluous (but otherwise harmless).